# How to transform picture on hover

Tags: html, css

When I move my mouse on a picture I would like that the picture zooms in, but that the size doesn't increase and that the text 'above' the picture slightly moves upward like in this example:
https://vikingco.com/en/mobile-vikings/

I already tried to browse the source code, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: For this kind of thing, try to use your browser's (or Firebug's) Web Inspector (right-click on the element -> Inspect Element). You'll be able to see exactly which CSS rules are applied between hover states and much more.

Comment: If you inspect the link, it looks like they're using an image as the background of a link and the :hover selector that adds `transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1)`. You could probably use :hover to add some css to make the text appear slightly higher as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've done it with CSS3 transitions. Taking some bits from their website, this shows an approach for the background image that can then be applied to the captions, etc.

Given this HTML:

```
<article class="grid-50 tablet-50 phablet-100 item-holder">
  <a href="/en/mobile-vikings/news/new-website-same-spirit/" class="item" style="background-image:url(https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pulse-be-media/content/uploads/2015/04/Pulse-2.jpg);"></a>
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="label action">Mobile Vikings</span>
    <span class="label action">Viking Talk</span>
    <span class="label action">VikingCo</span>
    <h3><a href="/en/mobile-vikings/news/new-website-same-spirit/">New website, same spirit</a></h3>
   </div>
</article>
```

They apply a transition to the `.item` that will animate all CSS properties:

```
.pulse .item-holder .item {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  -ms-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  filter: alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: .8;
}
```

and this `:hover` psuedo-class defines a scaling transform that is animated by the above transition:

```
.pulse .item-holder:hover .item {
  -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
  -ms-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
  transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
  filter: alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The whole thing needs wrapping in a container that defines a style of `overflow:hidden`.

This seems reasonable enough, so you could use it as a basis for your own code. Here is a fiddle showing it working with the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/q32stv45/1/